# How to startActivityForResult in RecyclerView adapter and override onActivityResult?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The `startActivity` in `recyclerView adapter` works fine but when I try to `startActivityForResult` in `recyclerView adapter` and I override the `onActivityResult` (in mainActivity) not works properly.

Comment: Please provide the code where you tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong it's not for your adapter to handle what to do on click. I would suggest that you, that you create a interface to create a listener:

```
public interface AdapterItemClickListener<T>
{
    void onItemClicked(final T item);
}
```

Then in your adapter constructor you have something like this:

```
private final AdapterItemClickListener<Object> _listener;
ListAdapter(final AdapterItemClickListener<Object> listener)
{
    _listener = listener;
}
```

so when you bind (I have no code so i'm supposing you're using a RecyclerView.Adapter)

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position)
    {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> _listener.onItemClicked(getItem(position)));
    }
```

your activity will need to implement the interface then inactivity you will have to create your adapter like this:

```
_adapter = ListAdapter(this);
```

end add this method

```
  private void onItemClicked(final Object item)
    {
       startActivityForResult(Intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin you can try pass a function as a param to your adapter like this inside you class Adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(val context: Context, 
                val list: List<Any?>,
                val onClickFunction: ((Any?) -> Unit)? = null) {
    // previous class's properties and functions ..

    fun override onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
        // previous code ..
        holder.whatEverYouWantClick.setOnClickListener {
           this@MyAdapter.onClickFunction?.invoke(list.get(position));
        }
    }
}
```

and in your "setRecyclerView" function you put this:

```
mRecyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(context, listOfWhatEverIWant) {
    // the on click will run here

    // storage the results ..

    this.finish()
}
```

If you don't understand what I'm doing, I'm passing a function to the adapter runs on one specific position element is clicked, this function set the results and finish to return back the result for the caller activity.